# Certificate for rabbitmq using Let's Encrypt

Tags: rabbitmq, lets-encrypt

I am trying to generate certificates to use SSL for authenticating rabbitmq.

I'm quite confused since to create a certificate using certbot (let's encrypt) I need to provide a domain name.

Any one have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You should actually use OpenSSL ..

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee you replied to my other post yday. I've attemped tls-gen (works localhost), OpenSSL (didn't work), Certbot (requires domain name). I've actually attempted 3 - 4 tutorials for OpenSSL with no luck. There must be something I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Study the `tls-gen` source code to set up your own CA. You can also use `make CN=` to generate a cert for a host other than `localhost`.

Comment: @daudnadeem , i think you should go step by step . First create self signed certificates , next configure RabbitMQ to support TLS using the certificates  , next sort out the client authentication issue . Where are you stuck currently...